# How can I read a nested object from Apollo cache by its ID?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, graphql, apollo-client

I'm a little new to GraphQL and I'm building an app with React and Apollo Client.

When my app starts I fetch pretty much all the data I'll need with one GraphQL query in the topmost component in my React app. In a component further down the component tree I want to directly fetch a model by its ID. How on earth do I do that?

For example say my initial gql query is:

```
query User($id: ID!) {
user(id: $id) {
  username
  todoLists {
    id
    title
    todoList {
      todoListId
      id
      name
      updatedAt
      todo {
        id
        title
        content
        updatedAt
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How would I then fetch via local cache a todo with an ID of say 1?

Sure I could fetch the whole user again and map over the object but that seems wrong.

I've tried using readQuery but I always end up getting a "Can't find field..." error. Should I be using a local resolver?

Whats best practice?

Any tips with an example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it, but the recommended way would be [readFragment](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/).

This would require you to turn the "todo" part of your query into a fragment, but that's probably something you'll want to do anyway.

Using fragments will make it explicit to Apollo that a "todo" is a "todo" is a "todo" regardless of which query it's appearing in. And readFragment / writeFragment let you work with that "todo" directly, without worrying about which query it came in from or which query it needs to write to.